# Push a hash into an array in a loop rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, hash

I am trying to add hashes to an array whilst iterating through an each loop. Here's my controller code: the line I'm struggling with is setting the @royaltiesbychannel variable in the each loop:

```
def royalty(isbn)  
 sales_hash_by_channel = Sale.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn).group_by(&:channel_id)
 sales_hash_by_channel.each do |ch_id, sale_array|
  @royaltiesbychannel = Array.new() 
  value_total_by_channel = sale_array.sum(&:value) 
  quantity_total_by_channel = sale_array.sum(&:quantity)      
   @isbn.rules.each do |rule|
   next unless rule.channel_id == ch_id   
   case quantity_total_by_channel
   when 0..5000  
   @royaltiesbychannel = @royaltiesbychannel << {ch_id => value_total_by_channel * 0.5}
    # (some other case-when statements)             
  end
 end
end
```

In the console, when I set the ch_id and the value to something new and push the new values into the array:

```
@royaltiesbychannel = @royaltiesbychannel << {ch_id => value_total_by_channel * 0.5}
```

I get a nice array of hashes:

```
[{1=>100000.0}, {2=>3000.0}]
```

However, when I do @royaltiesbychannel.inspect in the view, I get just one key-value pair:

```
[{2=>3000.0}]
```

For ref:

```
@royaltiesbychannel.class = Array
@royaltiesbychannel.class = 1
@sales_hash_by_channel.class = Hash
@sales_hash_by_channel.size = 2
@isbn.rules.size = 4
```

So it looks like the push into the array is overwriting rather than adding. What am I doing wrong? Have I completely missed the point on how loops and .push work? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: for one thing, you should put all that logic in your models :)

Comment: So true. I wondered about getting the thing to work first then refactoring...

Comment: @royaltiesbychannel = @royaltiesbychannel << {ch_id => value_total_by_channel * 0.5} why are you equating royaltiesbychannel to itself? you can do without the = sign, and thats probably where you're overwriting

Comment: and maybe you could refactor first and fix the bug in the process :) refactoring it into a cleaner more understandable code can clear things up for you, showing you why it wasnt working in the first place :)

Comment: also, you have an isbn argument on your method, which you are not using?

Comment: Thanks for both answers - I ticked one and upped the other, sorry I can't choose both. Thanks, @corroded, for tips. In honesty, this code is in the controller because I can't figure out how to call a method from a model - it's next on my research list. I think I'll end up ditching the isbn argument as I've duplicated that effort in the code itself. Basically I have a huge amount to learn.

Comment: no problem, basically if you put all that code in your Sale model, you can use it on a Sale instance like so @sale = Sale.new(), @sale.royalty or on the Sale class: Sale.royalty

Comment: That is brilliant. Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@royaltiesbychannel` initialization is inside the first loop, so every time it starts that loop again it empties the array. Move it outside the loop and you should get the result you want.

```
def royalty(isbn)
  @royaltiesbychannel = Array.new()
  sales_hash_by_channel = Sale.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn).group_by(&:channel_id)
  sales_hash_by_channel.each do |ch_id, sale_array|
    value_total_by_channel = sale_array.sum(&:value) 
    quantity_total_by_channel = sale_array.sum(&:quantity)      
    @isbn.rules.each do |rule|
      next unless rule.channel_id == ch_id   
      case quantity_total_by_channel
      when 0..5000  
        @royaltiesbychannel = @royaltiesbychannel << {ch_id => value_total_by_channel * 0.5}
        # (some other case-when statements)             
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing the array within the loop:
`@royaltiesbychannel = Array.new()`

It is being re-initialized each time, therefore you get only one result. Move it outside the each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `@royaltiesbychannel` to a new Array object during each iteration over `sales_hash_by_channel` should you be instead initialising it once outside of that loop instead?

Comment: hey @madlep, could you edit this answer, I accidently click down vote and it is locked now. going to revert it once you edit the answer plz. thanks!